# Differential Equation - initial value problem with defined domain interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:I\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a $C^1$ map and consider the differential equation

$$x''(t)=-f'(x(t))$$

If $x:[a,b] \rightarrow I$ is a solution to the above equation, then

$$t\rightarrow \frac{(x'(t))^2}{2}+f(x(t))$$ is a constant map.

Given interval $[0, \delta]$ with $\delta > 0$:

\begin{cases}
x''(t)=-(x(t))^{-3}   \\
x(0)=1\\
x'(0)=0
\end{cases}

Show that for sufficiently small $t>0$, we have

$$x'(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{1-x(t)^2}}{x(t)}$$

So this is a problem i struggled a bit on. And I finally got the solution to it:

Let $f(x):=\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}$, then $f'(x)=x^{-3}$. If $x(t)$ is a solution, then

$$E(t)=\frac{(x'(t))^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2x(t)^2}$$ and $E(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$

Therefore, $(x'(t))^2=\frac{1}{x(t)^2}-1$

Since $x''(0)=-1<0$, we have $x'(t)<0$ when t>0 is sufficiently small. Hence we have $x(t)<1$ and

$$x'(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{1-x(t)^2}}{x(t)}$$

I could follow the solution steps. But my question is how did they come up with the auxiliary function $f(x):=\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}$?

I'm pretty sure i could have solved it on my own if i were given this function. Which step or what would motivate this $f$?

Comment: You have the right hand side of $x''(t)=-(x^{-3}(t))$ which you can see as $f'$ in the first equation you stated such that $f'(y)=-y^{-3}$. You integrate then to obtain $f$.

Comment: ok im stupid.....this really drove me crazy ...thanks

Comment: (After pulling the $-$ into the $f'$ in the first équation you stated)

Comment: Not stupid, happens to everyone once in a while :-)